# Is it possible to filter out objects of an array in ElasticSearch documents?

Tags: elasticsearch

For documents like this:

```
{
    {
        "id": 1,
        "vehicle": "car",
        "equipment": [
            {
                "v_id": 11,
                "gps": false,
                "color": "yellow"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "vehicle": "bus",
        "equipment": [
            {
                "v_id": 34,
                "gps": false,
                "color": "red"
            },
            {
                "v_id": 99,
                "gps": false,
                "color": "yellow"
            },
            {
                "v_id": 10,
                "gps": true,
                "color": "red"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

is it possible to retrieve both `vehicle: bus` and `vehicle: car` documents, and then on top of that filter out the unnecessary `equipment`?

E.g., expected result for searching bus and car, but only `equipment` with `gps: true` is included in the results.

```
{
    {
        "id": 1,
        "vehicle": "car",
        "equipment": []
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "vehicle": "bus",
        "equipment": [
            {
                "v_id": 10,
                "gps": true,
                "color": "red"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If equipment has type `nested` you can add a bogus `nested` query, which will perform inner_hits retrieval:

```
DELETE test

PUT test
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "id": {
        "type": "long"
      },
      "vehicle": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "equipment": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "v_id": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "gps": {
            "type": "boolean"
          },
          "color": {
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

PUT test/_bulk?refresh
{"index":{"_id": 1}}
{"id":1,"vehicle":"car","equipment":[{"v_id":11,"gps":false,"color":"yellow"}]}
{"index":{"_id": 2}}
{"id":2,"vehicle":"bus","equipment":[{"v_id":34,"gps":false,"color":"red"},{"v_id":99,"gps":false,"color":"yellow"},{"v_id":10,"gps":true,"color":"red"}]}

POST test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "vehicle": [
              "bus",
              "car"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "equipment",
            "query": {
              "term": {
                "equipment.gps": true
              }
            },
            "inner_hits": {}
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "_source": {
    "excludes": "equipment"
  }
}
```